# Can I click the same gylphicon class and toggle between two functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, toggle

Is it possible to click a glyphicon and toggle between two functions?
I declared a glyphicon pencil here

```
var tgtEditLink = document.createElement("a");
        tgtEditLink.href = "#";
        tgtEditLink.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Edit');
        var tgtEdit = document.createElement("i");
            tgtEdit.classList.add("glyphicon", "glyphicon-pencil", "white", "tgt-edit");
            tgtEdit.title = "Edit";
        tgtEditLink.appendChild(tgtEdit);
    tgtDragbar.appendChild(tgtEditLink);
```

users can click this class to enable the "edit" function on my application. I then want to be able to click the same glyphicon and disable said function for another one.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.tgt-edit', function rearrange() {
    $('#align-src-col').sortable(sortableOptionsSrc);

    return false;
});
```

The above code will let users edit their text.

I want to be able to click the pencil again, '.tgt-edit', to disable edit, and enable another function. Is this possible in javascript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the class of the element so it no longer has `tgt-edit` and has the class that the other operation is delegated to.

```
$(document).on('click', '.tgt-edit', function rearrange() {
    $('#align-src-col').sortable(sortableOptionsSrc);
    $(this).toggleClass(["tgt-edit", "tgt-other"]);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks! i figured I needed to introduce another class to handle each function.